# Access denied mysql server

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set up mysql on my Mac, but every time I type mysql on the command line I get:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'arlet'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

I type mysql -u root -p, and I get the same error.

I do not know if the server was set up correctly, because in the tutorial I am watching they activated it from preferences but in the installation package I got I did not have that option. 
When I installed it I got a password and did not write it down, so I tried to reset it using the instructions in the manual Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems and no results. Please help.

Edit: Alright, I think it's best to delete mysql from my computer and reinstall it. I have tried sudo `rm /usr/local/mysql` and it does not work. How can I remove it?

Comment: You set a password for your database. But in your project  $password filed is empty.

Comment: How about uninstalling it fully and re-installing it - this time make sure you have a note of any password it gives you.

Comment: How do I uninstall it fully? it does not let me